# What is the pKa of iodous acid?

Tags: acid-base, ph

Searching the web readily gives the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of hydroiodic acid, hypoiodous acid, and iodic acid, however, extensive searching did not result in any value of the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of iodous acid. So I am wondering if this value has been documented before, and if it hasn't, then what progress has been made to determine its $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$?

Comment: That's because iodous acid is less stable than the others you mention.  Sorry I could not provide a more direct answer, but iodous acid is barely even known.  What is known, now, is what you are up against.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodous_acid

Comment: There is a question posted on the Q&A site CheggStudy that reads: "Determine the pH of a 50 mL solution of a 0.15 M iodous acid (HIO2). The Ka of iodous acid is 2.9×10−5. ". Although the answer to the question is behind a paywall, if we trust the question itself then the pKa of iodous acid is 4.5. This is a somewhat dubious source though.

Answer (score 3):

According to Schmitz [[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/kin.20344)], $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{HIO2})\approx 6$ at $\pu{25 °C}$ (numerical references for the bibliographical entries have been updated):

> Stanisavljev [[2](https://doi.org/10.1002/bbpc.19971010708)] has proposed a correlation between thermodynamic values of oxo-halogen ions and has obtained $ΔG_\mathrm{f}^\circ (\ce{IO2-}) = \pu{−51.8 kJ mol−1}$. He has also estimated the dissociation constant of $\ce{IO2H}$, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{IO2H}) = 4$, and obtained $ΔG_\mathrm{f}^\circ (\ce{IO2-}) = \pu{ −75 kJ mol−1}$. However, this value introduced in the above equation leads to $K_\mathrm{C}^\circ = \pu{2.8e12}$ and an impossibly large value of $k_\mathrm{+C}^\circ$. His correlation supports the idea that $k_\mathrm{+C}^\circ$ is very large but overestimates $ΔG_\mathrm{f}^\circ (\ce{IO2-})$ and probably also the dissociation constant of $\ce{IO2H}$. **Figure 1** shows known $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values of oxy-halogen acids, including the value of $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{BrO2H})$ [[3](https://doi.org/10.1021/j100055a051)] not considered by Stanisavljev, and suggests that $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{IO2H})$ is closer to $6$ than to $4$.
>
> [image]
>
> **Figure 1.** $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values of oxy-halogen compounds $\ce{XOH}$ (•) and $\ce{XO2H}$ (◦).

#### References

1. Schmitz, G. Inorganic Reactions of Iodine(III) in Acidic Solutions and Free Energy of Iodous Acid Formation. *International Journal of Chemical Kinetics* **2008**, 40 (10), 647–652. https://doi.org/10.1002/kin.20344.
2. Stanisavljev, D. Consideration of the Thermodynamic Stability of Iodine Species in the Bray-Liebhafsky Reaction. *Berichte der Bunsengesellschaft für physikalische Chemie* **1997**, 101 (7), 1036–1039. https://doi.org/10.1002/bbpc.19971010708.
3. Faria, R. B.; Epstein, I. R.; Kustin, K. Kinetics of Disproportionation and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of Bromous Acid. *J. Phys. Chem.* **1994**, 98 (4), 1363–1367. https://doi.org/10.1021/j100055a051.